# The path I gave to the application gives an error

Tags: python

path:

[image]

code:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', '1')))

import unittest
from not_string import not_string

class TestNotString(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_string(self):

        data = 'candy'

        result = not_string(data)
        self.assertEqual(result, 'not candy')
        self.assertIsInstance(result, str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I run the code with the vscode code runner and it runs without any problems, but if I run the code with the terminal, it gives the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'not_string'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python will only find module `not_string` if you run your code from directory `1` (since Python always looks in the current directory) or `2` (since you change `sys.path` to look in `../1` and `2` is the only sister directory - taking the `abspath` is of no help since you'll only see `../1` if you're in `2`). Don't mess with `sys.path` in code, it's error prone (as you've found out) and fiddly. Put the full path to `1` in `PYTHONPATH` and you'll have no problems finding module `not_string` where ever the code is run from and whatever code is `import`ing module `not_string`.